# How to find sum of a column between a given date range, where the table has only start date and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql table userDistributions like this : 
`user_id, start_date, end_date, project_id, distribution` 

I need to write a query in which a given date range and user id the output should be the sum of all distributions for every day for that given user. 
So the output should be like this for input : '2-2-2012' - '2-4-2012', some user id :

 `Date    SUM(Distribution)

  2-2-2012  12 

2-3-2012  15 

2-4-2012  34`

A user has distribution in many projects, so I need to sum the distributions in all projects for each day and output that sum against that day.

My problem is what I should group by against ? If I had a field as date (instead of start_date and end_date), then I could just write something like 
 `select date, SUM(distributions) from userDistributions group by date;` 
but in this case I am stumped as what to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your database needs a calendar table.  It makes these kinds of queries much easier.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: You almost never need calendar tables with PostgreSQL, `generate_series` is much nicer.

Comment: Do you expect to see data for a date w/ 0 projects?

Comment: @Mike well it would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to produce your dates, something like this:

```
select dt.d::date, sum(u.distributions)
from userdistributions u
join generate_series('2012-02-02'::date, '2012-02-04'::date, '1 day') as dt(d)
  on dt.d::date between u.start_date and u.end_date
group by dt.d::date
```

Your date format is ambiguous so I guess while converting it to ISO 8601.

Comment: This is just awesome, is generate_series a postgres specific or standard with all other DBMS ?

Comment: @Rohit: I'm pretty sure it is PostgreSQL-specific but it is so incredibly useful that it really should be in the standard.

Comment: @Rohitchauhan It's a non-standard PostgreSQL function.

Answer (score 2):

This is much like @mu's answer.
However, to cover days with no matches you should use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT d.d::date, sum(u.distributions) AS dist_sum
FROM   generate_series('2012-02-02'::date, '2012-02-04'::date, '1 day') AS d(d)
LEFT   JOIN userdistributions u ON d.d::date BETWEEN u.start_date AND u.end_date
GROUP  BY 1
```

Comment: Yeah, this handles the "would be nice" situation of showing dates with no matching userdistributions records.